# totally transparent border

Tags: css, border, transparency

Simple Problem

Goal: Make a border (left and right) **completely** transparent so the body background color could be seen through.

Attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRQmY/

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div class="trap">
    Make the white borders transparent, so when I change the background color the background color will be seen through the borders.
    I've tried rgb() with opacity but no luck
</div>
<div class="trap2">
   This is what I'd like but I'm setting the border = bg color;
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {background:#eee;}
#wrap {padding:50px;}
.trap {
width:350px;
background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-right: 30px solid transparent;
border-left: 30px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 30px solid rgb(216, 199, 143);
}
.trap2 {
width:350px;
margin-top:100px;
background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
border-right: 30px solid #fff;
border-left: 30px solid #fff;
border-bottom: 30px solid rgb(216, 199, 143);
}
```

I've tried many of the workarounds to no avail to my specific problem.

Do you have any tricks left in your bag?

Comment: are you sure you don't just want margins?

Comment: he wants to have bottom border like trapezium, btw. it works for me on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Hah..Found the answer seconds before hitting submit.

Make sure to set the background of the element you want to be transparent to: `background:none;` or nothing at all.

Edit: thanks David Thomas

If you don't, the border will be (completely) transparent. But the border is, effectively, 'drawn over' the background-color of the element; so that background-color is visible 'through' the transparent border.

Comment: No: the `border` will be (completely) transparent. But the `border` is, effectively, 'drawn over' the `background-color` of the element; so that `background-color` is visible 'through' the transparent `border`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the border's background is your div's background, not the body. Read this article for reference: http://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/

This code:

```
#yourElement {
-moz-background-clip: padding;     /* Firefox 3.6 */
-webkit-background-clip: padding;  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
background-clip: padding-box;      /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
}
```

makes the border stay outside the div, so with a transparency set you see the body background's color, not the div background color.

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C9gJQ/
I used a partial transparency for the border, so you can see how it behaves, but you can change it to whatever you like.